# How to access different members of vector in a function

Tags: c++, vector, reference

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
   vector <class> abc;
}
```

when pressing some key

```
vector.push_back(class());
```

each loop

```
draw(vector)// what should the parameters be?
```

draw function

```
draw(vector,sizeofvector)
{
    for (int x=0;x< sizeofvector;x++)
    {draw vector[x];}
}
```

how should the parameters look? should i be passing an *abc?

Comment: `class` is a keyword in C++. It can never name a type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't intend to modify the vector, you usually pass it by const reference.

```
void draw(const std::vector<T>& v)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < v.size(); x++)
    {
        // draw v[x];
    }
}
```

You can also use iterators (this is often preferable).

```
void draw(const std::vector<T>& v)
{
    for (std::vector<T>::const_iterator x = v.begin(); x != v.end(); ++x)
    {
        // draw *x;
    }
}
```

The reason you don't pass it by value (`draw(std::vector<T> v)`) is because that would cause the entire vector to be copied every time you call the function, which is obviously incredibly inefficient. References mean that you just refer to the existing vector rather than creating a new one.

Comment: What about `iterators`, is just the fundamental glue in the STL.

Comment: And `auto` makes iterators even more convenient to type.

Answer (score 5):

In modern C++ this can be answered without correcting your errors:

```
for (const auto & x : vector) { draw(x); }
```

Alternatively (still in C++11):

```
for (auto it = vector.cbegin(), end = vector.cend(); it != end; ++it)
{
  draw(*it);
}
```

This might work in C++98/03, too:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0, end = vector.size(); i != end; ++i) { draw(vector[i]); }
```

Comment: can't you do the `i=0, ie=vector.size()` in C++98/03? Calling function on every iteration doesn't sound like fun.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: You can! :-)

Answer (score 0):

std::vector is the type.  You need to pass in an instance, so in your case:

```
draw(abc);
```

I also agree that your function should have prototype:

```
void draw( const std::vector<class> & v );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

void addOne(int& value)
{
    value++;
}

void print(int& value)
{
    std::cout << value;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> myVector;
    myVector.push_back(1);
    myVector.push_back(2);
    myVector.push_back(3);
    std::for_each(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), addOne);
    std::for_each(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), print);
}
```

Output: 234

*wrote by hand, compiler errors possible*